# How do you install the blaze module (Continuum analytics) in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, numeric, blaze

How do you install [blaze](http://blaze.pydata.org/index.html) natively (i.e., not in a virtual environment) in Python? The only instructions I find are on in the package's doc (see link), and [here](http://www.spontaneoussymmetry.com/blog/archives/436), in a virtual environment.

Comment: If you can do it inside a `virtualenv`, you can do it outside of it, there is absolutely no difference...

Comment: Fair enough--I hadn't played with them before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find any instructions anywhere online for this, but it's relatively straightforward.

About my platform/tools I used:

- Mac OSX (Mountain Lion)
- Python 2.7.3
- [homebrew](https://brew.sh)
- [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)
- It looks like you might need to install Cython, not sure as I already had it installed. You can do this with `pip install Cython`.

First, `brew install llvm`.

Here are the packages you need. You can `pip` all of them:

- `llvmpy`
- `numba`
- `meta`
- `ply`
- `blosc`
- `sphinx` -- for doc
- `aterm`

Once you've pipped everything,

- `cd /tmp` up to you, of course...
- `sudo git clone git@github.com:ContinuumIO/blaze-core.git`
- `cd /tmp/blaze-core`
- `sudo make build`
- `sudo make docs`
- `sudo python setup.py install`
  (Whether you need sudo depends on where you git things to, of course.)

I've had trouble running the tests, it looks like there's an error in an `__init__.py` file somewhere, but I can't be for sure. I can't get the unit tests to run, so take "successful installation" with a grain of salt. At any rate, I can do a spot check to see that the module imports correctly:

```
>>> import blaze
>>> from blaze import Array, dshape
>>> ds=dshape('2,2,int')
>>> a = Array([1,2,3,4],ds)
>>> a
Array
  datashape := 2, 2, int 
  values    := [CArray(ptr=140454075688080)] 
  metadata  := [manifest, arraylike] 
  layout    := Chunked(dim=0) 
[1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: Blaze is still pre-alpha at the moment. It can be installed without Anaconda though. The directions are here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze-core#alternative-installation

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't want to get roped in to a particular distribution of Python that you have to (ugh) pay for.

Comment: Anaconda is free. It's just like your system Python environment but with all the heavy packages prebuilt for you. It's freely available here: http://continuum.io/anacondace.html

Comment: These instructions are intended for people who would like to work with the standard distribution of Python. If you want to download the Anaconda distribution (which is currently free), that's up to you, of course.

Comment: It looks like aterm is (now?) packaged with blaze. No need to pip install it. Numba doesn't appear to be required either. However, pycparser is